# What a linux command take the result of "which" command as an argument and list the configuration file paths related to the command we gave to which?

Tags: linux, configuration, which

I can't recall that command and I can't even find it in Google. It's just killing me.

The usage of the command is like:

```
<that command> `which bash`
```

The output looks like:

```
/etc/skel/.bash_logout
/etc/skel/.bash_profile
/etc/skel/.bashrc
```

Took bush just for example of course. It may be any command.

Upd: I use the Redhat based OS.

Comment: Maybe something related to [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/281864/1086345) (if you are using a debian-based distro (deb packages) )? That solution does not use `which bash` but it shows you the configurations file for `bash` package

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `cat` and `locate` (instead of `which`) to find all config files for a specific command. Using your bash example, these one liners will give you what you want on Debian (dpkg) based systems.

```
cat $(locate bash.conffiles)
```

or

```
command=bash && cat $(locate $command.conffiles)
```

The output will be like in your example. On my machine it was as follows.

```
/etc/bash.bashrc
/etc/skel/.bash_logout
/etc/skel/.bashrc
/etc/skel/.profile
```

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I should have said that I use RedHat based OS. Your solve isn't working for me.